# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am trying to split a video into frames using FFmpegFrameGrabber (using code I have seen in tutorials) but am getting an exception as follows:

The code:

```
public BufferedImage getNextFrame() {
    FFmpegFrameGrabber fFmpegFrameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("resources/WebPage.mp4");
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
    opencv_core.IplImage i;
    try {
        fFmpegFrameGrabber.start();
        i = fFmpegFrameGrabber.grab();
        bufferedImage = i.getBufferedImage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            fFmpegFrameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bufferedImage;
}
```

The stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniavutil in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil.<clinit>(avutil.java:76)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec.<clinit>(avcodec.java:87)
at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.<init>(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:73)
at MP4VideoCodec.getNextFrame(MP4VideoCodec.java:16)
at MP4VideoCodec.<init>(MP4VideoCodec.java:12)
at main.main(main.java:7)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no avutil in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
... 15 more
```

How do I correct this exception?

Comment: are you using any editor such as eclipse ? if yes add the required jars to the project classpath. if you are not using any IDE then use the the command java -cp <list-of-jars>  your-code-file to add jars

Comment: I'm using an IDE, but what JAR do I need?